# Passing props to Children component from Parent state- React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

One can pass props to a component of a child route (while using React Router) by passing the props to the `Route` component for the child component and accessing it in the child component of this route by `this.props.route.propName`.

What about the props needed in a child component is a portion of the state of its parent component and not just some unrelated data to the components?

Since

- in `<Router />` the state of a parent `App` is not in scope, one cannot pass it to component in a sub `<Route />`, or
- all reference to a child component in the parent component is `{this.props.children}` and not `<aComponent data={this.state.somePortion} />`, one, again, cannot pass it through the syntax of expression `{this.props.children}`.

What is the catch?

Comment: Have you looked at redux/flux? Would probably help you solve this issue much easier

Comment: Yes I have looked at them. Because the `redux store` in upper in the main component and **provided** by a `<Provider/>`component in binding library `react-redux` all the components in the Router hierarchy can be fed by state by passing as props and accessing in component with `this.props.route.propName`. Thanks. But applying redux to my set up seems a bit difficult to me. Any solution without it. There MUST be some way, and not cumbersome too much.

Comment: Making use of some utilizers to make the life easier sometimes makes you loose some easiness, to regain that lost bits you need another construct that is potentially limit you in another little to big way. Using React Router makes the state in top component *un-passable* to the children components in this case for me for now. How I will make data flow down the way through components, ideally with props in React.js. Right? There must be some easy plain way.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Instead of store state within `App`, your state will need to be stored in the component that is rendering the routes then passed to the route. You can use the method below to wrap the component if you want it to maintains it current propType list.

If you cannot use `this.props.route.propName` another option would be to use an High-Order Component (HOC) that wraps your component and use it on the route, then pass the route props to the component you want to render.

```
const WrappedComponent = ({route}) => {
  return (<Component data={route.data} />);
};
```

You could then further extensibility you could pass the component to render to the route as well.

`<Route to='/about' component={WrappedComponent} data={[]} page={AboutPage} />`

Then update wrapped to something like this:

```
const WrappedComponent = ({ route }) => {
   const { page:Component, ...rest } = route;
   return <Component {...rest} />;
};
```

This uses some ES2015+ with the rest operator, but would allow more reuse on this HOC.

Comment: HOC or High Order component is a component that simply wraps another component. They are extremely useful in cases like this where you need to preform logic but don't want to add that logic to the inner component which tend to make the inner component more reusable.

Comment: Agian how can one reach the state that is in the top component by this construct you describe. The state is in the `App` component. Routes hierarchy as follows:  `<Router>
  <Route component={App}>
    </Route component={Sub}></Route>
  <Route>
</Router>`

Comment: It seems impossible without having something like the second bullet I describe unless one moves *React* `state` above the `<Router/>` of the *React-Router* out of the *top component* `App` by something like *Redux*

Comment: Right, I misunderstood. Yes you global state cannot be in `App` if needed in other places of the app.

Comment: And that *global state be in top component, here <App/>, and needed in other places, i.e. sub components* is a very typical thing in a React app, even possibly one of the reasons that you choose React.js to work with on front end development.

Comment: That state should be in the component that is rendering the routes. I typically call that component `App` so I misread. If you put it in the root you don't really need redux for instance.

Comment: Ok, that seems ok for this issue. How exactly I can pass the state of this top component to the routes down by props?

Comment: Should just be a a prop on the route using `this.state.propName`

Comment: ...and then access it in the `<Route/>` `component` by `this.props.route.propName`, ok got it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you change your abswer, if you want to, so that I accept it.